# Init event in OnDestroy() Statement Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, reload, scene

I would  init event in OnDestroy() on Unity3D Statement because after reloading scene some destroyed script get event and throw MissingReferenceException on gameObject.

here how I declare event :

```
 public delegate void SelectDelegate();
public static event SelectDelegate OnSelected;
```

and how I init it

```
void Destroy()
{
    OnSelected = new SelectDelegate(OnSelected); //Dont work :'(
}
```

How can I init  cleanly event for reloading scene

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am going to try a few things here:

1. In my dealings with Unity3D and C# I never instantiate a delegate as you do in the Destroy() method. Once declared, it can be accessed. When you register a delegate an instance should be created for you. See #4.
2. OnDestroy() is probably not the best place to init anything as it is called before that GameObject is destroyed. Therefore whatever you initialize will be gone soon.
3. I normally register delegates with something like `myClassInstance.Onselected += MyHandlerFunction;`. This is normally done in the OnEnable() function. To clean up I remove my delegates in the OnDisable() function with `myClassInstance.Onselected -= MyHandlerFunction;`.
4. Before dispatching an event always check it is not null with something like `if( OnSelected != null ) OnSelected();`.
5. If you want to avoid having a specific GameObject being destroyed when you load another scene use the [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) class.
6. Shouldn't Destroy() be OnDestroy()?